# Is there any difference between star-convex and radial?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, convex-geometry

Wikipedia's [Star domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) article claims:

> A similar, but distinct, concept is that of a radial set.

but the definitions seem to be equivalent. Is there some subtle difference I'm missing, or is the claim in the article wrong (or just imprecise, and referring to difference in statement of definition rather than non-equivalence)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|xy=0\}$. Then $C$ is a star domain. But it is not a radial set. The difference is that in the definition of radial set, you look at *all points in the entire space* for that line segment, not just at the points in $C$.

Comment: So it's just the technical issue of radius being 0 in some directions? Union of star convex set with ε-ball is radial?

Comment: Yes and yes (in the sense it would be radial at the center of the added ball).

Comment: OK I think my misunderstanding of "radial" is even greater, and likely a result of the (IMO wrong) claim that radial has any relationship to star-convex. At least as I understand it now, not just a star-convex set, but *any* subset of the vector space, becomes radial at $x_0$ if you add an ε-ball centered at $x_0$. This completely mismatches with my presumed (IMO natural) meaning for "radial", which would be that the set is completely described by a chosen center point and a "radius" along each unit vector.